# How does one get about having multiple web service requests from the same controller?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am able to successfully make web service requests however was curious how one is able to make multiple calls in one view controller.

For example

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
   didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [xmlData appendData:data];
}
```

would that not intercept all connections? That is I could have 2 web service calls and it would basically call the same functions? Slightly confused here or maybe not doing a good job asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    NSURLConnection *connection1;
    NSURLConnection *connection2;

    ... alloc, init, place the call to webservice, etc.

  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
          didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
  {
      if (connection == connection1)
      {
        do stuff
      }

      if (connection == connection2)
      {
        do other stuff
      }  
   }
```

Comment: but how can we differentiate about the response, if 3 w/s are called at a time giving SOAP:XML output. In that case don't you think, it need to be more manual & checking the conditions for with each tag.